# How to display multiple D3 visualizations on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm having trouble displaying multiple D3 graphs on one page. I have tried many things, but I can only seem to get one of the visualizations on the page, not both.

For the first visualization in HTML, I have:

```
<section id="first" class="main special">
<header class="major">
     <h2>Presidential Elections</h2>
</header>
<body>
     <div id="lineChart"></div>
     <script src="lineChart.js"></script>
</body>
</section>
```

My second visualization is similar in index.html:

```
<section id="second" class="main special">
<header class="major">
     <h2>House Seats Lost Based on Current President</h2>
</header>
<body>
     <div id="barChart"></div>
     <script src="barChart.js"></script>
</body>
</section>
```

In lineChart.js and barChart.js, I do not have either visualization labeled as 'svg', but instead 'lineChart' and 'barChart' respectively. The current code displays only the first (line chart) visualization, but I found that when I remove `<script src="lineChart.js"></script>`, the first (line chart) visualization disappears and the second (bar chart) visualization becomes visible. Does anyone have any idea or guidance on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, we can't help you without your code, [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should guide you.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without seeing the code. But you might selecting all `svg`s or `div`s and calling `remove()`. Look for code that does that, and try dropping the `remove()` call.